# How to combine a vector with a matrix in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I feel like an idiot, but I cannot seem to find a way to accomplish a very simple operation: add a vector as another column into a matrix in `numpy`. Here is the example:

```
x1 = np.array([1.0, 2.0])
x2 = np.array([[3., 4., 5.], [6., 7., 8]])
```

What I want to obtain:

```
array([[3., 4., 5., 1.],
       [6., 7., 8., 2.]])
```

So far the only working way I found was via `pandas`, which seems ridiculous.

```
def add_column_to_array(array, column):
    df = pd.DataFrame(array)
    df['newcol'] = column
    return(df.values)
```

Shouldn't there be a native `numpy` way to do this?

Comment: Use `np.column_stack`, `np.column_stack((x2, x1))`

Comment: Thanks! It did not work for my actual problem, because `x2` was stored as sparse. Once I forced it to be `dense`, `np.column_stack` worked.

Comment: `scipy.sparse` has its own `vstack` and `hstack` functions.  `np.column_stack` only works for `ndarrays` (numpy and its subclasses).  If both `x1` and `x2` are `sparse`, the `sparse.hstack` will combine them nicely.  But as usual, watch the dimensions and shapes when combining arrays (and sparse matrices).